# How do I bind a view model containing a list of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have my ViewModel that look like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public IList<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
    public IList<AttributeViewModel> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public IDictionary<int, bool> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeViewModel
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the corresponding view looks like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < Model.Attributes.Count; j++)
    {
        var attribute = Model.Attributes[j];
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attributes[j].Description)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Children[i].Attributes[attribute.AttributeId])
    }
}
```

When I try to do a post back of this view against my controller action, I get an InvalidCastException. Is what I'm doing possible in MVC?

---

For reference, here's my corresponding Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", new ParentViewModel
        {
            Attributes =
                new List<AttributeViewModel>
                {
                    new AttributeViewModel { AttributeId = 1, Description = "green" },
                    new AttributeViewModel { AttributeId = 2, Description = "spicy" }
                },
            Children = new[] { new ChildViewModel() }
        });
    }

    public ActionResult PostBack(ParentViewModel model)
    {
        // Does not work. Fails immediately
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

And my View:

```
@model ParentViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostBack", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{

    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count; i++)
     {
         for (var j = 0; j < Model.Attributes.Count; j++)
         {
             var attribute = Model.Attributes[j];
             @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attributes[j].Description)
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Children[i].Attributes[attribute.AttributeId])
         }
     }
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: My only stab from glancing over the syntax is `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Children[i].Attributes[attribute.AttributeId])` looks odd, I'm not sure if that is what needs to be done for a dictionary....but if attributes was a regular class the syntax would be `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Children[i].Attributes[j].AttributeId)`

Comment: `Children = new[] { new ChildViewModel() }` looks like an array when it should be an `IList`

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code, I didn't get an error...

Answer (score 0):

If these were regular classes not a dictionary, I know the For loop and Razor syntax would look differently. Maybe if you try modeling your loops and stuff from this syntax it will work.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.listModel.Count; i++)
    {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.listModel[i].LastName)    

        for (int m = 0; m < Model.listModel[i].anotherListObj.Count; m++)
        {
              @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.listModel[i].anotherListObj[m].FirstName)
        }
    }
```

Edit:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Children[i].Attributes[attribute.AttributeId])
```

Above it looks like it's trying to convert a List of Attributes to a Dictionary of attributes

Also my loop Syntax works over a View that expects 'SomeModel' and the definitions are like this

```
SomeModel
{
  List<ListClass> listModel {get;set;}
}

ListCLass
{
  List<yetAnotherList> anotherListObj {get; set};
}
```